# A error about "requestWindowFeature"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

```
package com.act;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Error occur at second line "Window". If someone is Chinese, please answer me in Chinese, because my English is not good.

Comment: requestWindowFeature should be called before super();

Comment: If you want full screen i have posted code snip , to try on.

Comment: @DeSI2, welcome to Stackoverflow, please could you post the error message?

Comment: @Robert now i solve the error

Comment: Is good to know that you can solved the problem. Please post your own answer

Answer (score 0):

Open `AndroidManifest.xml` file set theme in your activity

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

or

```
    this.supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override  
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  
//code that displays the content in full screen mode  
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,  
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);//int flag, int mask  

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

}
 Try this if helps let me know

Comment: And "unknown enity 'WindowsManager '"

Comment: what you mean by unknown entity ? you have to Import it , can you put log cat output here

Comment: can you put logcat ?